# How to specify last form in Windows forms application in Console Application?

Tags: c#, console

```
    static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Debug));
        thread.Start();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }

    static void Debug()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

I have something like that. It launchs a console and a windows form. What I want to do is Hide or close the console application without terminating the whole application and show it later by pressing a button or something like that from form. How can I prevent the application from closing?

Can't we just fit up a console in windows form? My real problem is I'm writting an windows forms application. Also I want a window (console window) that will execute and test some functions on windows forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar answered here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ea8b0fd5-a660-46f9-9dcb-d525cc22dcbd

Basically, seems like you need to call some windows API functions to show/hide the console.

Comment: Can't we just fit up a console in windows form? My real problem is I'm writting an windows forms application. Also I want a window (console window) that will execute and test some functions on windows forms.

Comment: I hate calling windows API functions :D

Comment: In that case...  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/701e02cc-ad77-46b9-b4fc-410bb3ff7a0d

Comment: Dont blame you but I think you are stuck with them in this case.  An alternative might be to create 2 applications- your winforms app, and a console app that references the winforms app assembly and (for testing purposes) spins up the main form the way that you are doing it here.  That way you can run your console test harness, or just run the winforms app unhindered by the console.

Comment: So after calling AllocConsole() it seems I have to create another thread for ReadLine()s ?

Comment: Yes- your main thread is busy running the message pump for your forms

Comment: Oh When I try close button on Console application whole application closes.. :( Can I catch an FormClose event or smt like that in Console Window so I can call FreeConsole thing.?

Comment: @haxxoromer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2790/discussion-between-chris-shain-and-haxxoromer)